# Does the Cuban healthcare system perform better than those of countries of similar economic strength?

Tags: healthcare

Cuba is frequently cited as an example of a country which has great healthcare considering its limited economic resources.  For example:

- [Salim Lamrani, *Cuba's Health Care System: a Model for the World*, Huffington Post](http://www.huffingtonpost.com/salim-lamrani/cubas-health-care-system-_b_5649968.html):

> According to the UN's World Health Organization, Cuba's health care system is an example for all countries of the world.
>
> The Cuban health system is recognized worldwide for its excellence and its efficiency. Despite extremely limited resources and the dramatic impact caused by the economic sanctions imposed by the United States for more than half a century, Cuba has managed to guarantee access to care for all segments of the population and obtain results similar to those of the most developed nations.

The article goes on citing statistics of an [infant mortality of 4.76/1000](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_countries_by_infant_mortality_rate) and a [health expectancy of 79.4 years](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_countries_by_life_expectancy).

- [Lucia Newman, *The truths and tales of Cuban healthcare*, Al Jazeera](http://www.aljazeera.com/indepth/features/2012/06/201265115527622647.html):

> Much of this praise is well-deserved. Despite its scarce resources, Cuba has one of the world's lowest infant mortality rates - just slightly lower than that of the US. Life expectancy is 77.5 years, one of the world's highest. And until not so long ago, there was one doctor for every 170 citizens - the highest patient-per-doctor ratio in the world.

Others, however, state that all is not as good as it seems:

- [National Review, The Myth of Cuban Healthcare](http://www.latinamericanstudies.org/cuba/health-myth.htm):

> Then there is the real Cuban system, the one that ordinary people must use — and it is wretched. Testimony and documentation on the subject are vast. Hospitals and clinics are crumbling. Conditions are so unsanitary, patients may be better off at home, whatever home is. If they do have to go to the hospital, they must bring their own bedsheets, soap, towels, food, light bulbs — even toilet paper. And basic medications are scarce. In Sicko, even sophisticated medications are plentiful and cheap. In the real Cuba, finding an aspirin can be a chore. And an antibiotic will fetch a fortune on the black market.

(...)

> In the Q&A, the kids spouted at him [[Cuban exile Ermando Valladeres](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Armando_Valladares)] the usual line about Cuba: health care, literacy, and blacks. They had been carefully taught it by their teachers. And Valladares answered, in essence, “It’s all untrue — a pack of lies. But even if it were true: Can’t a country have those things without dictatorship, without tyranny, without gulags, without torture — with freedom?”

It is difficult to reconcile the two.  By objectively measurable indicators, such as access to (preventive) care, health expectancy, infant mortality etc., does Cuban healthcare perform better than the healthcare for countries of comparable economic strength?  Or is there verifiable evidence that this is primarily a very well-constructed façade set up by the authorities in Cuba?

Comment: I'm wondering if both could be true. Certainly, the answer might be subjective if the different measures conflict.

Comment: @Oddthinking Maybe.  If preventive care is incredibly good so that most people will never have to go to poor quality hospitals, they could be, perhaps.

Comment: The National Review article has a quote from a visiting American doctor "The [Cuban] doctors are pretty well trained, but they have nothing to work with" which is probably accurate: capable staff but a lack of equipment and medicines.

Comment: Where do the figures for Cuba's infant mortality and life expectancy come from? Are they reliable?

Comment: @iamnotmaynard That would need to be considered for an answer to this question.

Comment: National Review doesn't even pretend to be a neutral source.

Comment: @gerrit - what would be an criteria by which you evaluate any answer's ability to correct for major self-reporting bias inherent in socialist economic/political systems? In other words, ANY statistics you see for Cuba are likely to be as much BS as statistics which you saw in former USSR, which was a lot of BS. Without defined evaluation criteria, ANY answer is either going to be "Cuba lies" or "Cuba is greate because their numbers are true" with no objective ability to decide between the two aside from someone's political biases.

Comment: In other words, this question is offtopic because there can't possibly be a source that's "more authoritative" than the source you're skeptical about. You either trust official propaganda #s from Cuba or you don't, but you can't have any data outside Cuban government's control that could be used to cross-check.

Comment: @DVK Cuba is not closed to foreigners.  If life expectancy is claimed to be 80 but in truth closer than 50, it should be obvious to any visitor that there are very few old people around.  I would like to see a source that is *neither* the Cuban government *nor* Cuban exiles, as neither are politically independent.  I realise independent journalism is likely difficult in Cuba, but clearly it is possible for American doctors to visit.  Are their (limited) observations consistent with a high life expectancy and low infant mortality?

Comment: @gerrit - *sigh*. Unlike you I actually lived in a socialist country. (1) Foreigners get to see what government officials want them to see. It's easy to see a wonderful healthcare system when you're shown a clinic for the elite - and trust me, there's a level of difference that's inconceivable to a westerner (2) In case of Cuba, foreigners (especially "American Doctors") to get to visit are ones who are predisposed to **like** Cuba and - at least unconsciously - be biased. People who are not pro-Castro don't tend to WANT to visit, or be allowed to.

Comment: @DVK I can't comment on your personal experiences.  Of people I know who have lived in nominally socialist countries, some think negatively, others are nuanced (how to interpret high votes for Die Linke in former east Germany?).  Some refugees from eastern Europe returned after spending time in west Berlin.  Some people I spoke who went to Cuba say they were free to go where they wanted and to speak to whom they wanted.  Others said they weren't.  The Cuban government has an interest in making it seem better than it is.  Its opponents have an interest in making it seem worse than it is.  Hard.

Answer (score 11):

**"Cuba has managed to guarantee access to care for all segments of the population"**

[This claim is true](http://www.medicc.org/publications/medicc_review/0905/mr-features1.html)

It's even part of the [constitution](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/Constitution_of_Cuba):

> Article 50: Everyone has the right to health protection and care. The
>   state guarantees this right;
>   - by providing free medical and hospital care by means of the installations of the rural medical service network, polyclinics,
>   hospitals, preventative and specialized treatment centers;
>   - by providing free dental care;
>   - by promoting the health publicity campaigns, health education, regular medical examinations, general vaccinations and other measures
>   to prevent the outbreak of disease. All the population cooperates in
>   these activities and plans through the social and mass organizations.

**"and obtain results similar to those of the most developed nations."**

This claim is difficult to handle, it depends on what is your interpretation of "results".

**Statistics of infant mortality and a health expectancy**

Historically, Cuba has had good relations with UN dependencies like [WHO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_Health_Organization) or [PNUD](http://www.undp.org/content/undp/fr/home.html), and they usually cross-validate (at relatively small scale) the health-care statistics that the government provides, [with their own representatives inside the country](http://www.paho.org/cub/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=92:personal-ops-cuba&Itemid=237).

Examples of collaboration between WHO and Cuban health authorities:

1- [Country-wide research on Optic Neuropathy Epidemy in the 90-ties](http://www.nejm.org/doi/full/10.1056/NEJM199511023331803#t=articleBackground).

2- [Medical Education Cooperation with Cuba](http://www.who.int/workforcealliance/members_partners/member_list/medicc/en/)

3- [Publications from MECC about Cuba and Health Care](http://www.paho.org/cub/index.php?option=com_docman&view=download&alias=1465-compendio-medicc-review-1&category_slug=biotecnologia-para-la-salud-en-cuba&Itemid=226) (Mix of Spanish and English)

**"Hospitals and clinics are crumbling. Conditions are so unsanitary, patients may be better off at home, whatever home is."**

This varies a lot from province to province or even from hospital to hospital within the same province. There is no 'one size fits all' when talking about sanitary conditions of hospitals and clinics in Cuba.

You can find things like this:

Hospital in Las Tunas
[image: http://medicablogs.diariomedico.com/jlrodriguez/files/2013/06/HEG1-300x219.jpg]

Source: http://medicablogs.diariomedico.com/jlrodriguez/2013/06/25/hospital-universitario-ernesto-guevara-de-la-serna/

Or like this:

Hospital in Havana (capital)
[image: Hospital Julio Trigo]

Source: https://www.cubanet.org/noticias/hospital-julio-trigo-abandonado-y-con-mosquitos/

Or this:
https://panampost.com/belen-marty/2015/10/06/inside-the-cuban-hospitals-that-castro-doesnt-want-tourists-to-see/

**"And basic medications are scarce. (...) In the real Cuba, finding an aspirin can be a chore. And an antibiotic will fetch a fortune on the black market."**

It is not true that finding an aspirin is ALWAYS problematic. The problem in this case is that supply for ANY imported products in Cuba is unstable, including medication or raw materials for their fabrication. Aspirins may disappear from the market for a while, and the same can happen with soap, detergent, rice, toilet paper, gas, you name it. So the problem in this case is not the health care system *per se*.

Examples:

[Cuban Government Explains Shortages of 25 Basic Products](http://www.havanatimes.org/?p=106139)

[Cuba Is Trying Price Controls To Deal With Food Shortages](https://www.forbes.com/sites/timworstall/2016/12/08/facepalm-cuba-is-trying-price-controls-to-deal-with-food-shortages/#41eb348d7fab)

[Cuba's Tourism Boom Is Causing Food Shortages](https://www.eater.com/2016/12/8/13882552/cuba-tourism-food-shortage)

[Facing fuel shortage in Cuba, Havana diplomats roll up sleeves](https://www.reuters.com/article/us-cuba-energy/facing-fuel-shortage-in-cuba-havana-diplomats-roll-up-sleeves-idUSKBN179346)

**Interesting facts:**

Cuba's health expenditure per capita [is at least twice as much as other countries in the region](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_countries_by_total_health_expenditure_per_capita) like Mexico, Argentina or Brasil, who have stronger economies by far.

Many developed countries with a single-payer system (like Canada or Spain), have limitations in the types of care covered, for example not covering dental care or eye care. [The Cuban system covers both](http://www.medicc.org/publications/medicc_review/0905/mr-features1.html) (see also Article 50 of the constitution), albeit with many deficiencies in terms of supplies.